# How to retrieve data from Realm's Results instance?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I just start to learn Realm data persistence, I start it from a iOS test project.
The realm object is declared like this:

```
class AchievementRecord: Object {

    dynamic var dateID:String = "1111-00-00"
    dynamic var date:String = "0000-00-00"
    dynamic var apple:Int = Int(0)

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "dateID"
    }
}
```

I initialise the object in View Controller's `viewDidLoad()` method as this:

```
class AchievementRecord: Object {

dynamic var dateID:String = "1111-00-00"
dynamic var date:String = "0000-00-00"
dynamic var apple:Int = Int(0)

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "dateID"
}
}
```

then I declare another function to obtain the save data as:

```
let appleOn_05 = defaultRealm.objects(AchievementRecord.self).filter("dateID = '05-06-2017'")
print(appleOn_05)
```

In the console, Xcode says:

[image]

Because I need to retrieve the apple's number, which is 22 in the console. How can I retrieve the apple's number to demo it on the screen, how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u try appleOn_05!.apple

Comment: No, I have tried that and it is not working.

Comment: looks like appleOn_05 is a List of AchievementRecords. You need to enumerate through it, and get the first object and assign it to a AchievementRecord var, and then you can access the apple property.

Comment: How to approach this? Would you mind demo by code, that will be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results works like native Swift collections in many ways. If you are fetching a single object, you can just access it with Results.first `let appleOn_05 = defaultRealm.objects(AchievementRecord.self).filter("dateID = '05-06-2017'").first`

Subclasses of Object work like any other native class instance in Swift, so you can access their properties using the dot syntax.
`let apple = appleOn_05.apple`

Combining the two:

```
if let appleOn_05 = defaultRealm.objects(AchievementRecord.self).filter("dateID = '05-06-2017'").first {
    let apple = appleOn_05.apple
}
```

Comment: That is very helpful, I thought the filter will just return a single object and I now just figure out the filter actually return an similar Set stuff, the 'first' actually retrieve a single object. Now totally make sense. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem :) If you want to learn more about the `Results class`, have a look at the [official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html).